# Is possible T<T>

Tags: c#

I have some class, for example `A`, and others who extended `A (A1,A2)`. The `A` is a container - it has only fields, any methods and properties.

Another class is `B<T> where T : A`, and extends of `B (B1, B2)`

Is it possible do that in c#?

```
public List<T<T1>> DoSomething(object parameter) 
                                      where T : B<T1>, new() where T1 : A, new()
```

In that method i must dynamic create T (B1 or B2 or B3) object and fill that generic object dynamic created T1 objects (A1, A2, A3). Yup i probably can use Activator, but use new T() will be better and use less casts

Comment: Are `B1` and `B2` generic classes too?

Comment: B1 and B2 extended B, so yup, are generic

Comment: My head hurts...  Can you maybe spec out in C# an example of what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't compile?  That might be a better starting point.

Comment: @user1091406 `B1` could just as well have been a non-generic class that inherits from `B<A1>`, so I could not get that from the question.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a composite pattern?

Comment: In that method i must dynamic create T (B1 or B2 or B3) object and fill that generic object dynamic created T1 objects (A1, A2, A3). Yup i probably can use Activator, but use new T() will be better and use less casts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `T<T1>`

To clean it up a little:

```
public List<T> DoSomething<T, T1>(object parameter) 
      where T : B<T1>, new()   // this specifies T<T1> already
      where T1 : A, new()
{
}
```

<strike>And assuming `A` and `B` have default constructors, you don't need the `new()` constraints.</strike>

Comment: Firstly, you need to explicitly specify the type parameters in the definition of `DoSomething`. Secondly, just because `A` and `B` have default constructors doesn't mean any derived classes do. You do need the `new()` constraints.

Comment: @hvd: you're right on both counts. I forgot to put the `<T,T1>` back, silly. Edited. It was just a rough draft.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do it, but it would be annoying to use:

```
public List<TB> DoSomething<TA, TB>(object parameter)
    where TA : A, new()
    where TB : B<TA>, new()
{ }

var list = DoSomething<A1, B1<A1>>(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however you cannot use a type argument for `T` (which is not necessary anyway). In addition, you must specify `T` and `T1` as type arguments for the method

```
public List<T> DoSomething<T, T1>(object parameter)
    where T : B<T1>, new()
    where T1 : A, new()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I know what you're asking, it's possible - but you don't need the `List<T<T1>>`.

```
public class A {}
public class ADerived : A {}

public class B<Ta> where Ta : A
{
    public Ta a { get; set; }
}
public class BDerived<Ta> : B<Ta> where Ta : ADerived {}

public class Test
{
    public List<Tb> DoSomething<Tb, Ta>(Ta input) 
        where Tb : B<Ta>, new() 
        where Ta : A, new()
    {
        var list = new List<Tb>();

        var b = new Tb();
        b.a = input;

        list.Add(b);

        return list;
    }

    public int testThis()
    {
        var result = DoSomething<BDerived<ADerived>, ADerived>(new ADerived());
        return result.Count;
    }
}
```